# Can a capturing group be nested in a non-capturing group

Tags: regex, r

I try to get a FASTA header splitted using PERL-like regular expressions in R.

Some examples of input strings:

```
>P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B
>ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024146 (Bos taurus) similar to alpha-2-macroglobulin isoform 1
>ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024462 (Bos taurus) 47 kDa protein;>ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024466 (Bos taurus) 44 kDa protein
>Q3SX28 TREMBL:Q3SX28;Q5KR48 (Bos taurus) Tropomyosin 2
>P00761 SWISS-PROT:P00761|TRYP_PIG Trypsin - Sus scrofa (Pig).
```

And I want to get the information

- identifiers (P04259, ENSBTAP00000024146, ENSBTAP00000024462, Q3SX28, P00761)
- if available gene symbol like in case 1 (KRT6B)
- protein name (Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B, (Bos taurus) similar to alpha-2-macroglobulin isoform 1, (Bos taurus) 47 kDa protein, (Bos taurus) Tropomyosin 2, Trypsin - Sus scrofa (Pig))

My suggested regular expression is in R format:

```
^(?:>.*?(?:ENSEMBL:|SWISS-PROT:|TREMBL:))([A-Z0-9.-]+)(?:.*?Gene_Symbol=(\\S+)|\\s+|;\\S+ |\\|\\S+)(.*?)(?:;>.*?|\\n)
```

and in pcre format:

```
^(?:>.*?(?:ENSEMBL:|SWISS-PROT:|TREMBL:))([A-Z0-9.-]+)(?:.*?Gene_Symbol=(\S+)|\s|;\S+ |\|\S+)(.*?)(?:;>.*?|\n)
```

I tested the regular expression at regex101.com and the result is exactly what I want. But if I execute it in R every capturing group include the complete string. I think the special case that not every entry got a gene symbol produces some internal problems. Maybe its also a problem that I nested a capturing group in a non-capturing group.

```
> gsub(pattern = regex, replacement = "\\1", x = ">P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B", perl = TRUE)
[1] ">P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B"
> gsub(pattern = regex, replacement = "\\2", x = ">P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B", perl = TRUE)
[1] ">P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B"
> gsub(pattern = regex, replacement = "\\3", x = ">P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B", perl = TRUE)
[1] ">P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B"
```

The result of the regex101.com tests
[image: The result of the regex101.com tests]

So finally I want the green block, the red block (if available) and the orange block as results. Hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you post a link to the regex101 test you did? If `gsub` returns the input string, it means there was no match, so likely you made an error in translating the regex to R. Also, you don't want to use `gsub` for extracting groups - that's for replacing text.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tD2pF1/1 yeah I thought about it, but after checking the regex several times I cannot find any mistakes :(

Comment: The regex there is missing a `?` at the end and uses `\s` instead of `\s+`, however it should still work (if you're applying it to each line separately). However, are you sure it matches correctly? Some entries seem to begin in the middle of a line, your regex only allows matches from the start. Also, be sure to set the `(?m)` mode modifier if you're not applying the regex line-by-line, or `^` will only match once per string.

Comment: Do you mean in the last non-capturing group at the `.*` -> `.*?` The multiline flag is not necessary cause every FASTA header is read one by one, and I just want the first entry if there are multiple in a row.. therefore I use the `^`. The result from regex101.com is what I called correct, but R does not produce the same result even tho I put the missing `?`

Comment: If you want to *extract* substrings, why use `gsub`? Use `str_match` from stringr. Did you use ``\\`` or single backslashes? You need to double them.

Comment: OK, can you show the code you're using to define `regex`? Maybe the error is there?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I used gsub cause it was for me the easiest way of getting the first results I wanted.

Comment: `regex <- "^(?:>.*?(?:ENSEMBL:|SWISS-PROT:|TREMBL:))([A-Z0-9.-]+)(?:.*?Gene_Symbol=(\\S+)|\\s+|;\\S+ |\\|\\S+)(.*?)(?:;>.*?|\\n)"` its the same line as I wrote it above as "R formatted"

Comment: The reason is that you test against 1 string with your gsub. Thus, the last `\n` is a problem. Replace with `$`: `gsub("^(?:>.*?(?:ENSEMBL:|SWISS-PROT:|TREMBL:))([A-Z0-9.-]+)(?:.*?Gene_Symbol=(\\S+)|\\s|;\\S+ |\\|\\S+)(.*?)(?:;>.*|$)", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE)` Have a look at **[this demo](https://ideone.com/fHHjZ2)**.

Comment: Oh man Wiktor huuuge thanks! Big thanks to you guys for helping me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tested the string in the online regex tester, you used a multiline string. The last `\n` in the regex matches a newline, and thus, you had a match for `>P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B`.

You just need to replace `\n` with an end-of-string anchor to make it work with `gsub`:

```
x = ">P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B"
gsub("^(?:>.*?(?:ENSEMBL:|SWISS-PROT:|TREMBL:))([A-Z0-9.-]+)(?:.*?Gene_Symbol=(\\S+)|\\s|;\\S+ |\\|\\S+)(.*?)(?:;>.*|$)", "\\1", x, perl = TRUE)
gsub("^(?:>.*?(?:ENSEMBL:|SWISS-PROT:|TREMBL:))([A-Z0-9.-]+)(?:.*?Gene_Symbol=(\\S+)|\\s|;\\S+ |\\|\\S+)(.*?)(?:;>.*|$)", "\\2", x, perl = TRUE)
gsub("^(?:>.*?(?:ENSEMBL:|SWISS-PROT:|TREMBL:))([A-Z0-9.-]+)(?:.*?Gene_Symbol=(\\S+)|\\s|;\\S+ |\\|\\S+)(.*?)(?:;>.*|$)", "\\3", x, perl = TRUE)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/0YOB3o)

However, since you want to *extract* text, I'd suggest using your regex with the `str_match` from the *stringr* package:

```
> library(stringr)
> x = ">P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B"
> str_match(x, "^(?:>.*?(?:ENSEMBL:|SWISS-PROT:|TREMBL:))([A-Z0-9.-]+)(?:.*?Gene_Symbol=(\\S+)|\\s|;\\S+ |\\|\\S+)(.*?)(?:;>.*|$)")
     [,1]                                                                                       [,2]     [,3]   
[1,] ">P04259 SWISS-PROT:P04259 Tax_Id=9606 Gene_Symbol=KRT6B Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B" "P04259" "KRT6B"
     [,4]                               
[1,] " Keratin, type II cytoskeletal 6B"
```